# Firefox - Allowing about: protocol

Tags: firefox, protocols

I have custom (new tab page), and one of the features I want to add to it is a button that sends me to `about:debugging` or `about:profiles` tabs when using a hyper link or create a new tab with `url: "about:debugging"`

It gives me this error:

```
<span style="color:red;"> Content at http://127.0.0.1:5500/html.html may not load or link to about:debugging <span>
```

(ignore `http://127.0.0.1:5500/html.html` it's just for testing)

The same error fires when trying to open `file://...` as a hyper link too.

When searching for solution, I found out that you can fix the `file://...`  problem by adding this codes to `user.js` or manual to `about:config`

```
js
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "...");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

After adding these codes to `about:config` the hyper link for `fill://...` worked well, but I can't figure out the codes for `about:debugging` or any `about page`

I want a flag to stop the security for `moz-extension://88f48502-ba3c-4974-bd91-64fb956e54c6/index.html` to allow it to send me to `about:...` directly